# popup in tkinter with pygame that doest go away unless closed/pressed ok

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to get a popup for my pygame screen using tkinter, but i just want a simple messagebox that i pass in the message, and message type (like: "error"). What i don't know how to do is make it so that they can't avoid not answering it, if they click somewhere else it will not let the user do anything till they answer it, not even go to desktop sort of thing.

what i have so far:

```
def popUp(self, message, messagetype='Error'):

    #Tk().wm_withdraw() #to hide the main window

    messagebox.showinfo(messagetype, message)
```

Comment: You could use a thread to popUp a window.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: It is not recommended to take control of the whole desktop because if something wrong on your application and the control is not released, you will then need to restart the system to resume.

Comment: ok fair enough, so how, if clicked on my pygame application, would I force the user to have to answer the popup?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work your games's mainloop must be in a function (let's call it `play`). Let's say you have very simple code.

When a condition is met you can access the new function `popUp`. Which can have your tkinter window. When the button is pressed you can have its command as `...command=play)` if the player wants to restart. As the `popUp` function is not inside the mainloop the game will be unresponsive. An example:

```
    def play():
        while carryOn:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                        carryOn=False

                #Checking if a key is pressed and then responding e=with function in the sprite class
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    player.moveLeft(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    player.moveRight(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    player.moveUp(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    player.moveDown(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    player.moveLeft(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    player.moveRight(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    player.moveUp(5)
                if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    player.moveDown(5)
                #yourcondition
#               if ... :
#                   carryOn = False
#                   popUp()

                #Game Logic
                all_sprites_list.update()

                #Setting the background
                screen.fill(GREEN)

                #Now let's draw all the sprites
                all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

                #Refresh Screen
                pygame.display.flip()

                #Number of frames per second 
                clock.tick(60)
```

This is not full code - missing sprite class and code before that. You could then have your tkinter window (after importing tkinter) like:

```
global window #so it can be destroyed in the other function
window = Tk()
#message = ...
#message.grid ...
button = Button(window, text="restart", width=5, command=play)
button.grid # where you want it
```

The game will be frozen until the user presses restart (you may also want a `window .destroy()` in your code somewhere. You can adapt this to pretty much whatever you want but it is no where close to complete code. I hope this was useful.